# how to change code to download files from firebase storage instead of local

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to firebase, how can i change this from getting files from local to firebase storage

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        trackLbl.text = "Track \(trackID + 1)"
        // 1
        let path: String! = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/\(trackID!).mp3")
        let mp3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do
        {
            // 2
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: mp3URL as URL)
            audioPlayer.play()
            // 3
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateAudioProgressView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: false)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("An error occurred while trying to extract audio file")
        }

             }
```

Comment: Start from here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start